# Vector of structs: adding elements C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am reading my structs from a file, and I would like to add them to vector of structs.
Here is how it looks and works:

```
    typedef struct
{
    int ID;
    string name;
    string surname;
    int points;
}
Student;

int main()
{
    ifstream theFile("test.txt");
    std::vector<Student*> students;

    Student* s = new Student();

    while(theFile >> s->ID >> s->name >> s->surname >> s->points)
    {
        studenti.push_back(s); // here I would like to add this struct s from a file
    }

// here I want to print each struct's values on the screen, but the output is always ONLY last struct N times, and not all of them, each only once


    std::vector<Student*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it+=1)
    {
        std::cout << (*it)->ID <<" " << (*it)->name << " " << (*it)->surname <<" " << (*it)->points <<endl;
    }
```

What should I do so I can add my structs to a vector, and print them out normally (this print is only a check really, if the structs are properly loaded into vector)?

Comment: Why oh why the `typedef`?

Comment: And what's the file format? Does every student name consist precisely of two words?

Comment: Note that you don't have a vector of structs, you have a vector of pointers. All of which point to the same object...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how the code might look in modern C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

struct Student
{
    int ID;
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int points;

    Student(int i, std::string n, std::string s, int p)
    : ID(i), name(std::move(n)), surname(std::move(s)), points(p) {}
};

std::vector<Student> read_students(std::istream & is)
{
    std::vector<Student> result;

    std::string name, surname;
    int id, points;

    while (is >> id >> name >> surname >> points)
    {
        result.emplace_back(id, name, surname, points);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("test.txt");
    auto students = read_students(infile);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried emplace_back() a struct with four fields as in your example above but during compilation I get the error 'no matching constructor' so the example you provide appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @kometen: You're right, `Student` needs an appropriate constructor. I added one. Alternatively, you can say `result.push_back({id, name, surname, points});` and you don't need to add a constructor for that version.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: @kometen: No problem :-) Thanks for pointing out this error! For the record, I think `push_back` and aggregate-initialization is the better solution in this case; I wouldn't change the class definition just to accommodate emplacement. You can emplace when the class already comes with an appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 8):

Your mistake is to use pointers

```
std::vector<Student> students;

Student s;
while(theFile >> s.ID >> s.name >> s.surname >> s.points)
{
    students.push_back(s);
}
```

Now it will work.

The problem was that you were reusing the *same pointer* over and over. So you end up with a vector of pointers all pointing at the same object. Which will have values for the last student read in.

It seems a fairly common beginner trait to choose the complex alternative when the simpler one is correct so I would be interested to know why you chose to use pointers.

Comment: I thought it would be better if I used pointers since I need to call methods upon that list later in program. But I'm not experienced with pointers, and it was merely an idea. Not sure about pros and cons of pointers, tbh really.

Comment: You can call methods on the list without using pointers. It makes no difference, e.g. `students[i].some_method();`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store pointers to Students but not Students in the vector.

```
Student* s = new Student();

while(theFile >> s->ID >> s->name >> s->surname >> s->points)
{
    students.push_back(s); // here I would like to add this struct s from a file
}
```

You have allocated only one Student and each time you loop you are reading to it again and again.

Instead you should allocate a new student on each loop and read in to the new allocated memory.

```
Student* s;
int tmpId, tmpPoints;
string tmpname, tmpsur;

while(theFile >> tmpId >> tmpname >> tmpsur >> tmpPoints)
{
    s = new Student();

    s->ID = tmpId ;
    s->name = tmpname;
    s->sur = tmpsur ;
    s->points= tmpPoints;

    studenti.push_back(s); // here You push a pointer to the newly allocated student
}
else
{
    // There is error reading data
}
```

Don't forget to delete each student when you don't need the vector anymore.

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't work because you have one Student object and overwrite its members each time. Solution is to create a new Student object each time and pass a pointer to it to your vector:

```
std::vector<Student*> students;
int tmpId, tmpPoints;
string tmpname, tmpsur;

while(theFile >> tmpId >> tmpname >> tmpsur >> tmpPoints)
{
    Student* s = new Student();
    s->ID = tmpId ;
    s->name = tmpname;
    s->sur = tmpsur ;
    s->points= tmpPoints;

    students.push_back(s); // push a pointer to new student object
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```